# Replace value in assocative array PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to echo back an array to my javascript-application from PHP and change the values of a key based on it's match.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'Service' && $value == '1')
        $result[$key[$value]] = 'Dinner';
    if ($key == 'Service' && $value == '2')
        $result[$key[$value]] = 'Lunch';
    if ($key == 'Service' && $value == '3')
        $result[$key[$value]] = 'Breakfast';
}
```

Basically a database has numerical entries that corresponds to certain services and I'm trying to change the number to reflect the actual service but nothing I've tried so far has worked.

The only thing I'm certain of is that the above code is wrong and incredibly ugly. Is there a PHP-function that will do what I want?

On the other hand it might be easier to change the values on the javascript side but I haven't been able to do that either.

Using the ajax, angular $http method I retrieve the data with

```
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.userData = {};
    $scope.userData = response.data;
```

I've tried changin the response.data like so;

```
if (response.data.services == '1') {
    response.data.services = 'Dinner'; 
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Also tried

```
if ($scope.userData.services == '1') {
    $scope.userData.services == 'Dinner';
}
```

Doesn't work, but I suspect that even if it did it wouldn't alter all the values of the response.data.services to correctly display what service is being referred to.

Comment: `$ar=('', 'Dinner', 'Lunch', 'Breakfast'); ... if ($key == 'Service') $result[$key] = $ar[$value];`

Comment: @splash58 - Doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays for mapping/lookup purposes:

```
// One-time definition
$services = ['1' => 'Dinner', '2' => 'Lunch', '3' => 'Breakfast'];
// Your code...
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as &$row)
{
    // If the key is set and is mapped in $services
    if(isset($row['Service']) && isset($services[$row['Service']]))
    {
        // Then replace it
        $row['Service'] = $services[$row['Service']];
    }
}
```

I think your code would also work if you replace `$key[$value]` with just `$key`, but it's kind of wasteful to use a foreach loop if you only need a single, specific key anyway.

Comment: I tried using $key instead and no change. Your code looks of course a lot cleaner the issue is that the result might be several rows with $services being different for each row.

Comment: @HenrikM Right, that's a `fetchAll` there, my bad. Added a foreach loop around the if.

Answer (score -1):

The code should work correctly, the only thing you are missing here is that if you dont pass value as reference (&), so currently you cant make changes in your result array. You can also group a little

```
foreach ($result as $key => &$value) {

}
```

Comment: You only need `$value` to be a reference if you assign it directly. If you use `$result[$key]`, that's not required. Also, OP's code won't work correctly, because they use `$key[$value]` instead of `$key`.